# StackExchange.Redis with Azure: LockRelease is says lock is released but it doesn't appear to be

Tags: c#, azure, redis, stackexchange.redis, azure-redis-cache

Slightly at the end of my rope with this one :) I've got a prototype (too big with too many dependencies to share) that is using redis for multiple reasons - one of which is to store a serialized value, and control updates to that value by using a guard lock with `LockTake/Release` on a separate key.

The whole app looks a bit like this (NOTE: this snippet cannot reproduce my problem!):

```
using Nito.AsyncEx;
using StackExchange.Redis;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace RedisAzureLockingTest
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            AsyncContext.Run(async () =>
            {

                var cm = await ConnectionMultiplexer.ConnectAsync("blah:6379,ssl=false,password=blah,defaultDatabase=1,syncTimeout=5000");
                var db = cm.GetDatabase();

                // store key
                RedisKey key = "thisisourtest";
                await db.StringSetAsync(key, "initial value", flags: CommandFlags.DemandMaster); // SET

                // acquire lock
                RedisKey lockkey = "thisisourtest.lock";
                string locktoken = Guid.NewGuid().ToString();
                bool success = await db.LockTakeAsync(lockkey, locktoken, TimeSpan.FromDays(1), CommandFlags.DemandMaster);
                if (!success) throw new InvalidOperationException("Sure ok - lock couldnt be taken");

                try
                {
                    // do some stuff whilst the lock is taken

                    var oldval = await db.StringGetAsync(key, CommandFlags.DemandMaster);
                    if (oldval.IsNullOrEmpty) throw new InvalidOperationException("Key doesnt exist");

                    // persist an update
                    var newval = Guid.NewGuid().ToString();
                    await db.StringSetAsync(key, newval, flags: CommandFlags.DemandMaster); // SET
                }
                finally
                {
                    // release lock
                    if (!await db.LockReleaseAsync(lockkey, locktoken, CommandFlags.DemandMaster))
                        throw new InvalidOperationException("Should never occur - we couldnt release our own lock  is now locked forever!");

                    // double check that the lock has been released
                    var locktok2 = await db.LockQueryAsync(lockkey, CommandFlags.DemandMaster);
                    if (locktok2.HasValue) throw new InvalidOperationException("Should never occur - we couldnt release our own lock is now locked forever! Even worse- lock release lied about releasing itself");
                }

                Console.WriteLine("WORKED");
            });

            Console.ReadLine();
        }
    }
}
```

I've been testing locally with a simple single instance of redis and never had any problems, now I've come to try in another environment and have been using an Azure C0 Basic instance. Semi-reliably (I've managed to now set a local copy of my codebase pointing at the Azure instance) I can reproduce the problem - but have no idea what might be wrong or how to further debug the issue.

The behaviour that I'm observing is that:

1. `LockTakeAsync` is working correctly
2. My 'do stuff' bit is executing ok
3. `LockReleaseAsync` is appearing to succeed (returns TRUE) but the lock key is not removed from redis (confirmed using the cmdline redis-cli tool).

I've tried:

- Using the tracing of `ConnectionMultiplexer` - nothing untoward shows up
- Trimming down my app into a simple test case (see above) - but that doesnt reproduce the problem, so it must be something external
- Switch to non-async versions of the `LockTake/LockRelease` calls - problem remains
- Added logging around the `LockReleaseAsync` call (including `SET` "DEBUG" calls to redis to track - see below) to confirm the exact sequence of events
- Added the `LockQueryAsync` call in the above snippet to confirm that the lock is still held!
- Specifying that all of my commands should execute on the master replica.

The only thing that has given Running `MONITOR` on the redis instance and capturing traces of what SE.Redis is doing. When this executes locally and the app works correctly I get something like (key names changed):

```
1462360519.322029 [1 37.157.34.228:1995] "SET" "thisisourtest.93e6ca1d-3008-475f-92cb-2e7784e625cb.lock" "647672fd-ae06-4b6e-be67-341ac583a366" "EX" "86400" "NX"
1462360519.332884 [1 37.157.34.228:1995] "GET" "thisisourtest.93e6ca1d-3008-475f-92cb-2e7784e625cb"
1462360519.342668 [1 37.157.34.228:1995] "SET" "thisisourtest.93e6ca1d-3008-475f-92cb-2e7784e625cb" "ChIJHcrmkwgwX0cRkssud4TmJcsQARoSCQAAAAAAAAAAEQADAAAAAAAHIgNHQlAyCQi+koDo9oL9GToJCL6SgOj2gv0ZQgkIvvqI77mD/Rk="
1462360519.354847 [1 37.157.34.228:1995] "GET" "thisisourtest.93e6ca1d-3008-475f-92cb-2e7784e625cb.lock"
1462360519.364666 [1 37.157.34.228:1995] "SET" "DEBUG" "1"
1462360519.387834 [1 37.157.34.228:1995] "WATCH" "thisisourtest.93e6ca1d-3008-475f-92cb-2e7784e625cb.lock"
1462360519.387866 [1 37.157.34.228:1995] "GET" "thisisourtest.93e6ca1d-3008-475f-92cb-2e7784e625cb.lock"
1462360519.401686 [1 37.157.34.228:1995] "MULTI"
1462360519.401708 [1 37.157.34.228:1995] "DEL" "thisisourtest.93e6ca1d-3008-475f-92cb-2e7784e625cb.lock"
1462360519.401726 [1 37.157.34.228:1995] "EXEC"
1462360519.414845 [1 37.157.34.228:1995] "SELECT" "1"
1462360519.414862 [1 37.157.34.228:1995] "SET" "DEBUG" "2"
1462360519.424950 [1 37.157.34.228:1995] "GET" "thisisourtest.93e6ca1d-3008-475f-92cb-2e7784e625cb.lock"
1462360519.452993 [1 37.157.34.228:1995] "GET" "thisisourtest.93e6ca1d-3008-475f-92cb-2e7784e625cb"
```

When I run against Azure and recreate the problem, I get:

```
1462359810.253275 [1 23.97.166.137:1277] "SET" "thisisourtest.c26119b3-cc3e-48f1-8834-6c7b1d3afb69.lock" "35be6e88-7240-4772-ac2d-220a57ed1a79" "EX" "86400" "NX"
1462359810.256639 [1 23.97.166.137:1277] "GET" "thisisourtest.c26119b3-cc3e-48f1-8834-6c7b1d3afb69"
1462359810.258605 [1 23.97.166.137:1277] "SET" "thisisourtest.c26119b3-cc3e-48f1-8834-6c7b1d3afb69" "ChIJsxlhwj7M8UgRiDRsex06+2kQARoSCQAAAAAAAAAAEQADAAAAAAADIgNHQlAyCQi1nJ6N3IL9GToJCLWcno3cgv0ZQgkItYSnlJ+D/Rk="
1462359810.260233 [1 23.97.166.137:1277] "GET" "thisisourtest.c26119b3-cc3e-48f1-8834-6c7b1d3afb69.lock"
1462359810.262790 [1 23.97.166.137:1277] "SET" "DEBUG" "1"
1462359810.283693 [1 23.97.166.137:1277] "WATCH" "thisisourtest.c26119b3-cc3e-48f1-8834-6c7b1d3afb69.lock"
1462359810.283724 [1 23.97.166.137:1277] "GET" "thisisourtest.c26119b3-cc3e-48f1-8834-6c7b1d3afb69.lock"
1462359812.329321 [0 23.97.166.137:1257] "UNSUBSCRIBE" "U\xc7\n\xae\xa7\x1c\x84K\x8f\x1ft\x00\\j\xc2j"
1462359812.329374 [3 23.97.166.137:1256] "INFO" "replication"
1462359812.357770 [1 23.97.166.137:1259] "INFO" "replication"
1462359814.186895 [0 23.97.166.137:1312] "INFO" "replication"
1462359815.285593 [1 23.97.166.137:1277] "UNWATCH"
1462359815.285621 [1 23.97.166.137:1277] "SET" "DEBUG" "2"
1462359815.292618 [1 23.97.166.137:1277] "GET" "thisisourtest.c26119b3-cc3e-48f1-8834-6c7b1d3afb69.lock"
1462359815.302945 [1 23.97.166.137:1277] "GET" "thisisourtest.c26119b3-cc3e-48f1-8834-6c7b1d3afb69"
```

Which to me, looks like the `WATCH` has failed (is replication in Azure involved?) and the release fails. There does not seem to be a `DEL` command (never mind `MULTI/EXEC`) issued by SE.Redis. However `LockReleaseAsync` does not report this - and I also cant see in the MONITOR log a call that is affecting the key in question.

Stumped.

Any ideas as to how I can isolate this further? Attempts to build a small test case arent going anywhere quickly.

Cheers!

Comment: Have a look at http://redis.io/topics/distlock - it's not an answer, but without all the code, troubleshooting a distributed cache with distributed locks is really *really* hard. But this may help you narrow down.

Comment: Have you tried to simplify the case by running sync versions of LockTake/LockRelease and without any try/catch, just two calls one after the other?